# Error Handling in REST Webservice

Tags: rest-api, webservices, apexrest, apex-webservice, adderror

I have exposed this Apex class as a webservice. So far so good, as I get the response when this Webservice is called from ARC or POstman.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/ProcessAccount/*') 

global with sharing class AccountManager {

    @HttpGet
    global static list<Account> getAccountById() {

       RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
       String recordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Supplier_Account').getRecordTypeId();
       String accountId = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
       system.debug('The account is: ' +accountId);


       list<Account> result =  [SELECT ID, Supplier_ID__c,Name, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingPostalCode, 
                                    BillingCountry, Phone, 
                                    RecordTypeId, CreatedDate,LastModifiedDate, SystemModstamp 
                                    FROM Account 
                                    WHERE RecordTypeId = :recordTypeId AND Id = :accountId limit 1];

        system.debug('Check the list size ' + result.size());
        return result;

    }


}
```

My question is, how can I add error handling in this class. How can i make it good enough to confidentially deploy to production along with the test class. ?

Thank You

Comment: I don't see any system exceptions that could conceivably be thrown from this code unless you were to manually delete the Record Type. What errors are you concerned about?

Comment: As always, Thank you @David Reed.  I am concerned about any error that would prevent the response from being sent to the external app.

Comment: You could use try/catch blocks to capture any potential exception. Also, you could have a custom object to store the exception log as a separate record for every transaction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe that this code can throw any system exceptions at all. If no Accounts are found, or if the input is nonsensical, the class will simply return an empty list.

You need to add more code only if you want to provide a semantic response for the caller, such as "this request doesn't make sense", "no matching Account found", etc. In that case you would define your own error codes, check for the error state, and return some kind of composite response like

```
public class Response {
    List<Account> results;
    Integer errorCode;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a valid test class for your code above. However, this is not bulkified. Also I would note that you are returning a list of accounts, however, you only seem to be passing in 1 Account Id.

The one error I can see you checking for is that the Id being passed in as the path, you may want to check to see if it is a valid Account Id. You could perform a check like this:

```
Id myId = Id.valueOf(accountId);
if(Schema.Account.SObjectType == myId.getSobjectType())
{
    //continue
}else {
    //report failure back
}
```

```
@isTest
public class TestAccountManager
{
    @isTest
    static void test1()
    {
        Account a = new Account();

        a.Supplier_ID__c = '123';
        a.Name = 'Test Account';
        a.BillingStreet = '123 Fake Street';
        a.BillingCity = 'Springfield';
        a.BillingState = 'NJ';
        a.BillingPostalCode = '12345';
        a.BillingCountry = 'US';
        a.Phone = '123-456-7890';
        a.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Supplier_Account').getRecordTypeId();

        insert a;

        RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();

        req.requestURI = System.Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'services/apexrest/ProcessAccount/'+a.Id;
        req.httpMethod = 'GET';
        RestContext.request = req;
        RestContext.response = res;

        System.assertEquals(a.Id, AccountManager.getAccountById()[0].Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: @BrynaAnderson, Thank You. I dint mean to get help writing a test class. My apologies for not phrasing the question correctly. I do appreciate your help though,

Comment: @user4947 understood, I added a check for sObjectType of your Id, this could possibly be a potential failure checkpoint

Comment: Thank you!!. I appreciate your response.

Comment: @BryanAnderson Won't binding that Id into the query just return an empty list if it's the wrong type? I don't believe that throws an exception.

Comment: @DavidReed fair point, I wasnt sure if it would, just tried and confirmed you are correct

Comment: I truly appreciate your help @BryanAnderson and DavidReed. I was just testing it, and you answered before I could even ask.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to build your own rest response wrapper for different possible scenarios. And if you do this way, salesforce will return the rest response regardlessly, so the method return type will be void.

A over simplified example,

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/MyRestContextExample/*')
global with sharing class MyRestContextExample {

    @HttpGet
    global static void doGet() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse standardResponse = RestContext.response;
        String accountId =req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        List<Account> result = [SELECT Id, Name, Phone, Website FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId];

      if(result.isEmpty()){  
         //you can have own header or leave it
         standardResponse.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');        
         standardResponse.statusCode = 404;
         standardResponse.responseBody = blob.valueOf('No record found') ;
       }
      else if(!result.isEmpty()){     
         standardResponse.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');         
         standardResponse.statusCode = 200;
         standardResponse.responseBody = blob.valueOf(JSON.serializePretty(result));
      }
      ....etc

}

}
```

On top of that, if you have more complicated scenario for the return result, for example, instead of returning list of accounts, different list of Sobjects (Contacts, Cases) need to be return. You can build your own rest wrapper class.

```
Public class ResponseWrapper {
    Public List<Account> accs;
    Public List<Contact> cons;
    Public List<Case>   cases;
    ResponseWrapper(List<Account> para1,List<Contact> para2, List<Case> para3){
       this.accs = para1;
       this.cons = para2;
       this.cases = para3;
    }

}
```

Then just seralize it at the response body, 
A simplified example without null check

```
List<Account> accs = [Your SOQL];
List<Contact> cons = [Your SOQL];
List<Case> cases = [Your SOQL];
ResponseWrapper sample = new ResponseWrapper(accs,cons,cases)
standardResponse.responseBody = blob.valueOf(JSON.serializePretty(sample));
```

Comment: The result of a SOQL query is never `null`. The query as written above would throw an exception if no responsive records are found.

Comment: a bit of rush, code updated

Comment: Thank you @WayneNi, much appreciated and thank you again DavidReed

Answer (score 0):

Almost all code has the potential of errors. Good for you to be thinking about how to handle them!

`getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Supplier_Account')` will return null if the developer name isn't found. This seems like it would qualify as a "development time" exception (as opposed to runtime), and might be handled best with an assertion (`System.assert(getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().containsKey('Supplier_Account'), 'make sure this record type exists in the org!)`).

I've got a library - [Apex BOOST](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N4V00000IEUJvUAP&channel=recommended&tab=e) - that provides diagnostic helpers and persistent logging that might help you. For example, you could use the library's `Assert` methods (instead of the System ones), which throw catchable exceptions and can therefore be checked in unit tests.

Comment: Hi Steve, self promotion is allowed to some extent, especially as you disclose your affiliation with the promoted library. However, it is frowned upon to have _all_ your posts promote your library, which can lead to a community less welcome to your contributions. I'd recommend leaving those links out for a while and just have them in your bio. If you build up some credit here, and post some answers that have nothing to do with your library, it will restore a lot of that goodwill. Happy holidays.

Comment: Got it. Thanks very much @AdrianLarson